# How to make an expandable ring animation in UIView (something like submarine sonar)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

I'm wondering how to make an animation like sonar in submarine: thick ring which expand from the center and gets bigger and vanish while alpha down to 0;
I sae a few examples about CABasicAnimation but no clue how can I do this kine of animation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `CAShapeLayer` and animate its path for the basic animation. To also animate the alpha, it's a good idea to have both animations in an animation group so they are guaranteed to be in sync.

```
@implementation SonarView

+ (Class)layerClass
{
    // We want the base layer of this class to be a CAShapeLayer.
    return [CAShapeLayer class];
}

// There are various methods where you could set the animation up.
// I've chosen layoutSubviews since it's called when the view size
// changes as a side-effect.
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    CGRect rect1;
    CGRect rect2;
    UIBezierPath *path1;
    UIBezierPath *path2;
    CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer;
    CAAnimationGroup *group;
    CABasicAnimation *pathAnimation;
    CABasicAnimation *alphaAnimation;

    [super layoutSubviews];

    // The circle/oval in its largest size.
    rect1 = self.bounds;
    path1 = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:rect1];

    // Shrink it down to a 2x2 circle.
    rect2 = CGRectInset(rect1, (rect1.size.width / 2) - 1, (rect1.size.height / 2) - 1);
    path2 = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:rect2];

    // Configure the layer.
    shapeLayer = (CAShapeLayer *)self.layer;
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 1;
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
    shapeLayer.fillColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
    // This is the path that's visible when there'd be no animation.
    shapeLayer.path = [path1 CGPath];

    // Animate the path.
    pathAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"path"];
    pathAnimation.fromValue = (id)[path2 CGPath];
    pathAnimation.toValue = (id)[path1 CGPath];

    // Animate the alpha value.
    alphaAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
    alphaAnimation.fromValue = @(1);
    alphaAnimation.toValue = @(0);

    // We want both animations to run together perfectly, so we
    // put them into an animation group.
    group = [CAAnimationGroup animation];
    group.animations = @[ pathAnimation, alphaAnimation ];
    group.duration = 1;
    group.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;

    // Add the animation to the layer.
    [shapeLayer addAnimation:group forKey:@"sonar"];
}

@end
```

Comment: To make the opacity drop off a bit quicker use `alphaAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut];` This results in a nicer animation, IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

Swift Version DarkDust Answer

```
class Sonar: UIView  {

    override private func layoutSubviews() {
        var rect1:CGRect
        var rect2:CGRect
        var path1:UIBezierPath
        var path2:UIBezierPath
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        var group:CAAnimationGroup
        var pathAnimation:CABasicAnimation
        var alphaAnimation:CABasicAnimation

        super.layoutSubviews()

        // The circle/oval in its largest size.
        rect1 = self.bounds;

        path1 = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: rect1)

        // Shrink it down to a 2x2 circle.
        rect2 = CGRectInset(rect1, (rect1.size.width / 2) - 1, (rect1.size.height / 2) - 1)
        path2 = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: rect2)

        // Configure the layer.
        //shapeLayer = self.layer;
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 1;
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
        // This is the path that's visible when there'd be no animation.
        shapeLayer.path = path1.CGPath
        self.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)

        // Animate the path.
        pathAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "path")
        pathAnimation.fromValue = path2.CGPath
        pathAnimation.toValue = path1.CGPath

        // Animate the alpha value.
        alphaAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
        alphaAnimation.fromValue = 1
        alphaAnimation.toValue = 0

        // We want both animations to run together perfectly, so we
        // put them into an animation group.
        group = CAAnimationGroup()
        group.animations = [ pathAnimation, alphaAnimation ];
        group.duration = 1;
        group.repeatCount = FLT_MAX;

        // Add the animation to the layer.
        shapeLayer.addAnimation(group, forKey:"sonar")
    }
}
```

Comment: In Swift, it's a best practice to use `let` instead of `var` as much as you can. Here, you can convert all `var` to `let` since the variables are all only assigned to once. The compiler is smart enough to notice that, so you can leave the statements at the top (you don't need to assign in the same statement), like `let rect1:CGRect`.

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea, but you could try:

- Create a view, 2x2 and set the `view.layer.cornerRadius` to 1.0
- Do an animation where you set the layer's `affineTransform` to a scaled up version, over the duration of time you want
- Also change the `cornerRadius` to always be 1/2 of the width or height of the layer

Another option would be to draw a path of the circle, and animate the size of the layer up.

I haven't tried these, but shooting from the hip, that's where I would investigate.

Answer (score 1):

Swift 4.1 version of @DarkDust's Answer.

```
    import UIKit
    import Foundation

    class Sonar: UIView  {

        override internal func layoutSubviews() {
            let rect1:CGRect
            let rect2:CGRect
            let path1:UIBezierPath
            let path2:UIBezierPath
            let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
            let group:CAAnimationGroup
            let pathAnimation:CABasicAnimation
            let alphaAnimation:CABasicAnimation

            super.layoutSubviews()

            // The circle/oval in its largest size.
            rect1 = self.bounds

            path1 = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: rect1)

            // Shrink it down to a 2x2 circle.
            rect2 = rect1.insetBy(dx: (rect1.size.width / 2) - 1, dy: (rect1.size.height / 2) - 1)
            path2 = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: rect2)

            // Configure the layer.
            shapeLayer.lineWidth = 1
            shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
            shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
            // This is the path that's visible when there'd be no animation.
            shapeLayer.path = path1.cgPath
            self.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)

            // Animate the path.
            pathAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "path")
            pathAnimation.fromValue = path2.cgPath
            pathAnimation.toValue = path1.cgPath

            // Animate the alpha value.
            alphaAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
            alphaAnimation.fromValue = 1
            alphaAnimation.toValue = 0

            // We want both animations to run together perfectly, so we
            // put them into an animation group.
            group = CAAnimationGroup()
            group.animations = [pathAnimation, alphaAnimation]
            group.duration = 1
            group.repeatCount = Float.greatestFiniteMagnitude

            // Add the animation to the layer.
            shapeLayer.add(group, forKey:"sonar")
        }
    }
```